# How can I set multiple options on a model attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections, model

I'm trying to elaborate a model ( User for instance ) which can select a color from multiple options ( list )

How could I write it in the model and expose it in the view ?
I'd need to write a separate model only for the colors or is this approach going the right way :

```
//user.cs
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Colors Colors { get; set; }
}

//colors.cs
public class Colors
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public enum Colors ???
}
```

Comment: Is the list of colors already known and fixed or is it a dynamic list ?

Comment: Can users select multiple colors or just one color per user?

Comment: @Cubi already known and fixed

Comment: @Icemanind Just 1 color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there. The `Color` class isn't necessary if you're only wanting to provide a `Color` enum. Taking that into account, try this:

```
public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
}

public class User
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class UserColorAddEditViewModel
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public IList<SelectListItem> ColorSelectList { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the View, you can use the `UserColorAddEditViewModel` model and use the following `HtmlHelper`:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Color, Model.ColorSelectList)`

or as `Icemanind` mentioned, you can simply use:

`@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Color)` and you scrap the `ColorSelectList` variable (that means you can ignore the part below too).

If you decide to use the `DropDownListFor` helper, you'll need to initiate this variable within the defined `Controller` class, as shown below.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          UserColorAddEditViewModel Model = new UserColorAddEditViewModel();

          Model.ColourSelectList = Enum.
                GetValues(typeof(Color)).
                Cast<Color>().
                Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.ToString(), Value = ((int)c).ToString()})
                .ToList();

        return View(Model);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try it in a bit.. it's a bit confusing for me since I'm pretty much new at this, you mean to initialize the variables within the Controller as :
    `new ColourSelectList()` ??

Comment: I would use `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor` instead though.

Comment: color enum would be inside the user class ?

Comment: @Giulio Corkone Fullnior - as we're also accessing it within `UserColorAddEditViewModel` class, it needs to be outside of the `User` class. You can save the `User.cs` file with the enum outside of the User class, the compiler won't complain :).

Answer (score 1):

Your basic user class will look like this. I broke down your name property to first name and last name.

```
public class User
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I changed your colour class a bit in case (one day) you want to be able to go the database route instead of having a fixed set of colours. Name your class in singular form, not plural, for example Colour instead of Colours.

```
public class Colour
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A user view model will be passed to the view. This view model will contain user information and a list of the colours that will be used in the dropdown.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public int ColourId { get; set; }

     public List<Colour> Colours { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller's action method you create an instance of the view model above and populate it with user data and a list of all the colours.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int userId)
{
     // Get your user's information
     User user = userRepository.GetById(userId);

     UserViewModel model = new UserViewModel();
     model.Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
     // This can be separated into a repository class of its own if you need to use colours in another action method
     model.Colours = new List<Colour>
     {
         new Colour { Id = 1, Name = "Blue" },
         new Colour { Id = 2, Name = "Green" },
         new Colour { Id = 3, Name = "Red" },
         new Colour { Id = 4, Name = "Yellow" }
     };

     return View(model);
}
```

And then in your view you will have something like:

```
<h1>@Model.Name</h1>
<p>Please select a colour:</p>
@Html.DropDownListFor(
     x => x.ColourId,
     new SelectList(Model.Colours, "Id", "Name", Model.ColourId),
     "-- Select --"
)
```

Play around with the code to see how it works out for you.